# i need to Solve the error importing the NumPy library

Tags: numpy, object, attributes

#i need to Solve the error importing the NumPy library

arrange = np.arange(15)np.reshape(3, 5)

np.allclose(arange, [[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14]]) == True

#The error seems to tell me 'list' object has no attribute 'arange' I have tried
to define arange however it leaves me with syntax. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

arange = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)

np.allclose(arange, [[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14]]) == True

it was just a matter of spelling. all fixed. now for another coffee.